# ] SQLException caught, SQLState HY010 code:0- assuming deadlock detected, try:8 java.sql.SQLException: Invalid state, the Connection object is closed

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, jboss

I am getting this exception from Jboss 4.3.2GA connected with MSSQL 2008 in the defaultDS. In the environment last two weeks two time this error occurred and stopped the messaging.

There are MDBs listening the topic, suddenly messaging stopped, no messages in the JMS tables (Not even in the error queue). All the messages are lost. trying to find the root cause?

please give your thoughts on this ?

```
2017-06-12 22:52:39,487 WARN  [org.jboss.messaging.core.impl.JDBCSupport] Trying again after a pause
2017-06-12 22:52:39,764 WARN  [org.jboss.messaging.core.impl.JDBCSupport] SQLException caught, SQLState HY010 code:0- assuming deadlock detected, try:8
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid state, the Connection object is closed.
               at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC2.checkOpen(ConnectionJDBC2.java:1494)
               at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC2.prepareStatement(ConnectionJDBC2.java:2215)
               at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.BaseWrapperManagedConnection.doPrepareStatement(BaseWrapperManagedConnection.java:449)
               at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.BaseWrapperManagedConnection.prepareStatement(BaseWrapperManagedConnection.java:444)
               at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrappedConnection.prepareStatement(WrappedConnection.java:243)
               at org.jboss.messaging.core.impl.JDBCPersistenceManager$1AddReferenceRunner.doTransaction(JDBCPersistenceManager.java:1337)
               at org.jboss.messaging.core.impl.JDBCSupport$JDBCTxRunner2.execute(JDBCSupport.java:474)
               at org.jboss.messaging.core.impl.JDBCSupport$JDBCTxRunner2.executeWithRetry(JDBCSupport.java:512)
               at org.jboss.messaging.core.impl.JDBCPersistenceManager.addReference(JDBCPersistenceManager.java:1408)
               at org.jboss.messaging.core.impl.ChannelSupport.handle(ChannelSupport.java:227)
               at org.jboss.messaging.core.impl.postoffice.MessagingPostOffice.routeInternal(MessagingPostOffice.java:2212)
               at org.jboss.messaging.core.impl.postoffice.MessagingPostOffice.route(MessagingPostOffice.java:499)
               at org.jboss.jms.server.endpoint.ServerConnectionEndpoint.sendMessage(ServerConnectionEndpoint.java:763)
               at org.jboss.jms.server.endpoint.ServerSessionEndpoint.send(ServerSessionEndpoint.java:399)
               at org.jboss.jms.server.endpoint.advised.SessionAdvised.org$jboss$jms$server$endpoint$advised$SessionAdvised$send$aop(SessionAdvised.java:87)
               at org.jboss.jms.server.endpoint.advised.SessionAdvised$send_7280680627620114891.invokeNext(SessionAdvised$send_7280680627620114891.java)
               at org.jboss.jms.server.container.SecurityAspect.handleSend(SecurityAspect.java:157)
               at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor92.invoke(Unknown Source)
               at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
               at org.jboss.aop.advice.PerInstanceAdvice.invoke(PerInstanceAdvice.java:121)
               at org.jboss.jms.server.endpoint.advised.SessionAdvised$send_7280680627620114891.invokeNext(SessionAdvised$send_7280680627620114891.java)
               at org.jboss.jms.server.endpoint.advised.SessionAdvised.send(SessionAdvised.java)
               at org.jboss.jms.wireformat.SessionSendRequest.serverInvoke(SessionSendRequest.java:95)
               at org.jboss.jms.server.remoting.JMSServerInvocationHandler.invoke(JMSServerInvocationHandler.java:143)
               at org.jboss.remoting.ServerInvoker.invoke(ServerInvoker.java:862)
               at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.processInvocation(ServerThread.java:609)
               at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.dorun(ServerThread.java:421)
               at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.run(ServerThread.java:174)
2017-06-12 22:52:39,764 WARN  [org.jboss.messaging.core.impl.JDBCSupport] Trying again after a pause
```

Comment: Did you try [this solution](https://www.novell.com/support/kb/doc.php?id=7014490)?

Comment: Thank you fore the swift response, I found the same link but little bit concern about the suggested solution. I feel the error I am getting is when JBoss try to persist the message into JMS Database the exception is thrown (my understanding from the trace). The suggested solution is about when reading the message from the JMS Database ?